# javascript issues possible conflict

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, conflict

I have a small issue. I am using a google map with a Jquery plugin JPList which does some filtering and ordering of some results.

If I remove a bit of the jquery for the jplist plugin an onclick method works on the google map, but as soon as I put the jplist code back in the map click stops working.

I get no JS errors, and I am really struggling to get to the bottom of it.

What would be the best way to diagnose this? It would be really useful to know how to solve this.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Thanks

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var myOptions = {
           zoom: 4,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.900557, 174.885971),
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var icon = "img/marker.png";
        var icons = {
            'dflt': "img/marker.png",
            'selected': "img/white-marker.png"
        };
        var seletedMarker = null;
        $(function() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            // grab data attributes from html
            $('.row').each(function( index ){
                var rLat = $(this).data("coordinates").lat;
                var rLng = $(this).data("coordinates").lng;
                var rTitle = $(this).find('.itemtitle a').html();
                var rTel = $(this).find('.tel').html();
                var rAdd = $(this).find('.add').html();
                var contentString = '<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">' + rTitle + '</h4><strong>' + rTel + '</strong><br /><br />' + rAdd + '</div>';
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( rLat, rLng );
                var otherMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icons.dflt,
                    title: rTitle
                });
                // click actions
                google.maps.event.addListener(otherMarkers, 'click', (function(otherMarkers, index) {
                    return function() {
                        if (seletedMarker) {
                            seletedMarker.setIcon(icons.dflt); //revert seletedMarker's icon to .dflt
                        }
                        infowindow.setContent( contentString );
                        otherMarkers.setIcon(icons.selected); //Set marker's icon to .seleted
                        infowindow.open( map, otherMarkers );
                        seletedMarker = otherMarkers; //Remember the currently selected marker so it can be reverted to default next time round.
                    }
                })(otherMarkers, index));
                **/* this is what doesnt work */**
                $(this).click(function(){
                    google.maps.event.trigger( otherMarkers ,'click')
                });     
            });
**/* this is what stops it working */**
                $('#dynamiclist').jplist({
                    items_box: '.results',
                    item_path: '.row',
                    panel_path: '.panel',
                    items_per_page: '4000',
                    //checkbox filters
                    control_types: {
                        'cb_filters': {
                            class_name: 'control_checkbox_filters'
                            ,options: {}
                        },
                        'reset': {
                            class_name: 'control_reset'
                            ,options: {}
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Richard

Comment: Please show some code so that we can see what you're doing. Otherwise, open your browsers dev tools (F12) and use the JS console.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I often see is that a variable is overriden by your script.

As an example, if you load jQuery, then $ is set

you can add plugins to jQuery, then you will see $.jqURI for the jqURI plugin.

but it you load a script that already have jQuery of a jQuery plugin, it might reset completely the $ variable or nested properties and methods.

I would check in Firebug in the DOM tab to see which properties are present in all combinations of script you have (so if you have script A and B, I will check for A alone, B alone, then A+B).

In the situation of jQuery is implicated, look at jQuery.noConflict in jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just disable jQuery for this script? It is not needed anywhere.

Comment: sadly not the jplist plugin uses the jquery library

Comment: if it uses the jQuery then your question is answered. There is no conflict. The problem must be your code.